# Julia's PyPlot subplots title and subtitle overlapping

Tags: matplotlib, graph, julia, histogram, data-visualization

Thanks to [this answer for a related question in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44093831/3184351), I've written some Julia code to display histograms in a for loop.

```
using PyPlot

γvec = 0.1:0.1:0.9   # γ : fixed paramter
N = 1000     # N : number of samples for each γ

fig, axs = subplots(length(γvec), 1, figsize=(10, 6.18*length(γvec)), constrained_layout=true)
fig.suptitle("Distribution of eigenvalues of ρ at final time", fontsize=20, y=1)

# TL;DR
λ₁vec, λ₂vec = zeros(Complex{Float64}, N), zeros(Complex{Float64}, N);

for (iᵧ, γ) in enumerate(γvec)
  # println(γ)
  samples = [ myfunction(...) for _ in 1:N ];  # draw samples
  for i in 1:N
    λ₁₂ = eigvals(samples[i][1])  # calculate (real-valued) eigenvalues of ρ
    λ₁vec[i], λ₂vec[i] = maximum(real(λ₁₂)), minimum(real(λ₁₂))
  end
  axs[iᵧ].hist(λ₁vec)  # plot histogram of eigenvalues of ρ
  axs[iᵧ].hist(λ₂vec)
  axs[iᵧ].set_title("γ = $γ")
  axs[iᵧ].set_xlabel("eigenvalues of ρ")
end
gcf() # get current figure
```

To create the `fig`ure, I've adpated the syntax from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933922/3184351) and read [an e-book's sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/h-Klok/StatsWithJuliaBook/blob/0369445123804c1681209ed30d99044a9b10907b/1_chapter/piEstimate.jl#L12-L16).  Here's the figure that I've made.

[image]

Overlapping title and subtitle produced by Julia's PyPlot.  What can be done to properly display the title and subtitles?

---

Edited in reponse to comments.

I'm using the lastest version of Juno and Julia.

[image: graph overlapped]
Removed `y=1`, and the title goes below the first subtitle.

Comment: Don’t set y=1 in suptitle?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on matplotlib v2.2.2 and PyPlot.jl v2.8.1. There is no overlap.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for suggestion.  I've included a screenshot to show what it would look like without `y=1`: title now overlaps with the graph.

Comment: @hckr I'm using matplotlib v3.0.3 with Python 3.6.7.

Comment: Oh, I see, the GUI cuts the figure off at the height of your screen.  Don't make your figure so large if you want constrianed_layout to do anything sensible.  (note that if you save the figure, it looks OK)